# passport.authenticate('local', { successReturnToOrRedirect: '/'} ) never returns to previous route. Only redirects

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, passport.js

```
const router = require('express').Router()
const User = require('../models/user.model')
const { body, validationResult } = require('express-validator')
const passport = require('passport')



router.get('/login', ensureNotAuthenticated, async(req, res, next) => {
res.render('login')
})
router.post('/login', ensureNotAuthenticated,
passport.authenticate('local', { 
successReturnToOrRedirect: '/',
failureRedirect: "/auth/login",
failureFlash: true
}))
```

if for example a user tries to access a protected route, say 'auth/profile', he gets redirected to the log in page, but on successfully logging in, he gets redirected to the route specified in 'successReturnToOrRedirect'. I was using passport 0.4.1 and there, it redirected back to the previous protected route after the user has successfully logged in

Answer (score 4):

Same problem here while upgrade passportjs from v0.4.1 to v0.6.0. There is a workaround solution to add a `keepSessionInfo: true` to your authentication function.

```
passport.authenticate('local', {
    successReturnToOrRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/login?attempt=true',
    keepSessionInfo: true,
})
```

You may also find discussions in https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/919